# Store specific value in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store specific value in laravel. Here **Select User** not required field but in foreach loop hidden field **proj_id** must has value. Suppose there are 5 rows and I want to store only 2nd and 5th **user** along with **proj_id** from hidden field. Here I want to mention that in controller I also kept delete operation so that I can remove previously inserted **SAME PROJECT ID** related record. For example If I want to store 2nd and 3rd user, that time only 2nd and 3rd users record will remove first then insert. In my code there are logical error but could not find solution. Thanks in advance

```
<form action="{{ url('/save-project') }}" method="POST">
 <tr>
 @foreach($projects as $val)
   <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="proj_id[]" value="{{$val->id}}"> 

    <select name="user_id[]">
         <option value="">Select User</option>
         <option value="2">x</option>
         <option value="4">y</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  @endforeach
 </tr>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Controller

```
 $countUserID = count($user_id);
 assign_project::where('flag','Y')
                 ->WhereIn('proj_id',$request->proj_id)
                  ->delete();

for($i=0;$i<$countUserID;$i++){
  $assign_project = new assign_project();
  $assign_project->proj_id = $request->proj_id[$i];
  $assign_project->user_id = $request->user_id[$i];
  $assign_project->save();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON fields are gaining more popularity since they became officially supported in MySQL 5.7.8. Even the popular Spatie Laravel Medialibrary package use them, so why shouldn’t we?

To create a JSON field, all we need to do in Laravel migration is use `->json()` method:

```
$table->json('array_data');
```

Next, you need to tell your model to cast that column from JSON to an array automatically:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'array_data' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

This way, you will receive `$array_data` as array and don’t need to do `json_decode()` at all.